# Django South: How to create rules for a Custom Field?

Tags: django, django-south

I've create a custom field "Private FileField". I'm not able to get it to work with django-south.

My understanding of South field rules is based on
http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part4.html#tutorial-part-4 and
http://south.aeracode.org/docs/customfields.html

Relevant snippets are:

```
class FileField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'upload_to' in kwargs:
            raise Exception("%s expects one keyword arg 'upload_to'" % (self.__class__))
        self.upload_to = kwargs['upload_to']
        del kwargs['upload_to']
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        super(FileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
rules = [
  (
    (FileField,),
    [],
    {
        "upload_to": ["upload_to", {}],
    },
  )
]

from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules(rules, ["^private_filefield\."])
```

Running a manage.py schemamigration my_app_name --auto fails with the following message:

`Exception: <class 'private_filefield.fields.FileField'> expects one keyword arg 'upload_to'`

(this happes when site-packages/south/orm.py", line 46, in FakeORM is called)

Full code can be found on:
http://bitbucket.org/vanschelven/django_private_filefield/src/tip/private_filefield/fields.py

=== Edit: text below added ===

This is the relevant section of the generated 'models' section of the auto-generated migration:

```
    'mailfile.mailfile': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'MailFile'},
        'creation_date': ('django.db.models.fields.DateField', [], {'auto_now_add': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
        'expires_on': ('django.db.models.fields.DateField', [], {'default': 'datetime.date(2010, 7, 16)'}),
        'file': ('private_filefield.fields.FileField', [], {'max_length': '255'}),
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'owner': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': "orm['auth.User']"}),
        'secret': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '40'})
    }
```

Note the lack of 'upload_to' as paramter to 'file'.

Comment: Could we see the model using the FileField ? from the error messages it seems that it lacks the upload_to parameter.

Comment: The model's FileField does have the upload_to parameter. But the auto generated 'models' section of the migration does not have this parameter. So I guess my question can be reduced to "how do I make sure the auto generated model will also contain this 'upload_to' parameter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, I tried to write this in a comment, but the lack of paragraphs hates me.

I just set up your custom field as-is in a Django app, and created a dummy model to use it. South works perfectly. I added another FileField and was able to run `schemamigration --auto` with no issues. So, I'm pretty sure you have South set up correctly.

Honestly, did you check your *model* to make sure that it has the `upload_to` parameter? That causes exactly this error message (and it would mean South did *exactly* what you told it to do).

Comment: Hi Luke, I'm no longer/ not able to reproduce this problem, though it's been bugging me consistently for a while, some grepping around also showed it's now no longer a problem. Many thanks for going through the trouble of helping me!

Comment: Ha! I wasn't crazy after all... I just re-experienced this in South 0.7; but the problem is fixed in 0.7.3. Thanks again Luke for helping me out here